# How to sync deleted branches from git repo?

Tags: git, github

I am aware of how to delete branches locally using

`git branch -d <branch_name>`

and how to delete both locally and remotely using

`git push origin --delete <branch_name>`

I recently learnt how to prune obsolete branches as well, only when doing so I see the changes reflected in the remote branch list when running this command

`git branch -r`

But the branch listing seems to still display me all the branches whenever I run this command

`git branch`

Is there a command to sync the changes from the remote to be reflected in the local branch listing, so that when I delete a branch on github I can pull the updates of all the branch changes i.e which one have been deleted and which still remain, into my local environment?

Comment: So do you want this: You do a sync and your Git realizes that some local branch has been deleted on the remote, so then it automatically deletes yours?

Comment: Part two: If so, do you immediately see potential problems with this?

Comment: could you provide some examples (e.g. the output you get when calling each of your commands)

Comment: I do like to see if git has such a feature, i took a look and only think related to removing branchs a bit close to what is the desired was  "git prune"  but just for remote references on git.